# nextToken in "queryAll" Query type

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I have a very simple Schema Structure in my AWS AppSync using DynamoDB as backend.

```
    type Demo {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        date: String!
    }

    type DemoConnection {
        items: [Demo]
        nextToken: String
    }
input ListFilter {
    limit: Int
    nextToken: String
}
```

And i have this query to list all Demos

```
listAllDemo(input: ListFilter): DemoConnection
```

For which the resolvers looks as -

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Scan",
    "limit": #if($context.arguments.limit) $context.arguments.limit #else 10 #end,
    "nextToken": #if($context.arguments.input.nextToken) "$context.arguments.input.nextToken" #else null #end
}
```

And Response Mapping Template as

```
{
    "items": $util.toJson($context.result.items),
    "nextToken": $util.toJson($context.result.nextToken)
}
```

I created some 13 records to test the "nextToken". It returned a token along with 10 results and i used it to fetch the other results.
There is some other API which deletes these records from DB. WHat happens is even when i am now having 7 records in DB, "`listAll`" returns the nextToken , which it should not, though using this nextToken the next resultset is blank.

I am unable to understand why i am getting this nextToken even when records are not there.

Comment: The strange thing i found was if those records are deleted via AWSAppSync mutations, then only nextToken refreshes itself. !!!!

Comment: Sorry for the issues. We just tried to reproduce this, creating a Amazon DynamoDB based sample. We started with 6 items, then we jumped to 12, then back to 9, all of which had a limit of 10 items. We only got a non-null token at 12. Can you share some more details about your run - specifically, whether you adjusted item count, your api id, your request id, region, and a rough timestamp.

Comment: Jeff, i recreated the issue again. This time i tested for 23 records in DynamoDB. There are 3 records that are coming in the last page. Delete these particular records(not mutation) and fire the GraphQL query again with the token(of not these 3 records) but with previous 11-20 records. In  the query of 11-20 records i should get nextToken null, however it returns me the token and though upon using it it return items and nextToken null. My problem is with token i am getting after deletion in query for 11-20 numbered records.

Comment: For region, i am in free trial us-east-2.